# SQL Full Text Search - What determines order when rank values are equal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have FTS running on SQL and in most scenarios it seems to be working as expected. A simple example of the query I'm using:

```sql
select 
    a.ArticleId, a.Title, a.[Rank]  
from 
    Articles a inner join 
    freetexttabale(Articles, Title, @searchTerm) as rankedTitle 
        on rankedTitle.[key] = a.ArticleId
order by 
    rankedTitle.[rank] desc
```

An example of the results:

```
+===========+===============================+======+  
| ArticleID | Title                         | Rank |  
+===========+===============================+======+  
| 232       | Notifications budget guidance | 212  |  
+-----------+-------------------------------+------+  
| 65        | Notifications                 | 212  |  
+-----------+-------------------------------+------+
```

To my mind, since both items have a rank of 212, I would have thought article 65 (the second one) should have appeared first. So the question is, what does SQL FTS do in these situations?

I know that the rank value might change from one query to the next, but these are pretty consistent and it's tough to find any related information on Microsoft's site to explain the behavior.

Comment: A resultset is no more ordered than what you define in your order by clause. Any rows with the same rank will have no particular order. That is standard SQL behavior.